# Error while playing mp3 file in Turbo c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mp3, turbo-c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<conio.h>

//my mp3 file is in root of drive C
void main()
{
printf("playing file==>C:\preview.mp3");
system("C: & preview.mp3");

getch();

}
```

This code is not working... on this TC (Turbo C++)
illegal command error... 
help

Comment: Try this "C:\\preview.mp3", see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Comment: I don't want to play beep sound using /a ....i want to play mp3 file using above code....

Comment: Any body please answer this!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

system() is not a valid command in Turbo C++. That's only for visual studio's C++. And also remember that your MP3 file might be above 16 bit and that Turbo C++ runs over MS-DOS which is a 16 bit operating system.